# I am training my own dataset and I got InvalidArgumentError in tf.image.decode_jpeg

Tags: tensorflow

Part of the code:

```
label = input_queue[1]
image_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])    
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)    
image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, image_W, image_H)
```

Error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Invalid JPEG data, size 300
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg_2 = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReadFile_3)]]

  File "C:/Users/MCRC/made/catdog/training.py", line 97, in <module>
    run_training()

  File "C:/Users/MCRC/made/catdog/training.py", line 60, in run_training
    CAPACITY)

  File "C:\Users\MCRC\made\catdog\input_data.py", line 100, in get_batch
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)

  File "D:\A3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_image_ops.py", line 345, in decode_jpeg
    dct_method=dct_method, name=name)
```

I am using Tensorflow-GPU 1.0 with Python3.5 in Windows. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the image (or one of the images, I can't tell since it depends on how `input_queue` is constructed) is not a valid JPEG image (and the file contents are 300 bytes).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found out a file which is not a pic.